# Remove node from failover cluster without access to said cluster or domain

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, clustering, windows-server

I have a server running Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2008 R2.   The server used to be part of a SQL cluster but it is now standalone and no longer has access to the cluster.

I want to repurpose this server as a standalone database server.   When I try to remove it from the cluster within Installation Center it fails the 'Cluster service verification' step and won't allow me to continue.

On a related note I am also unable to install Service Pack 2 for the same reason.

Is there a way to remove this server from a cluster that no longer exists?  Or am I forced to do a clean install of Windows and then a clean install of SQL Server?

Comment: When you say it used to be part of WSFC/SQL FCI and now it is not, how did you removed it from old cluster ? I believe you did not removed it correctly.

Comment: @Shanky it was simply physically removed from the data center.  At the time it was believed it would be wiped and sold.  But circumstances change.

Comment: That is not the correct approach, it should first have been removed from SQl Server cluster than windows cluster. I guess this is why you are facing the issue

Comment: @Shanky I know that it's not the correct approach.  In case it wasn't clear I am asking if there is a way to resolve this issue. I'm NOT asking what the correct approach is.